# How to do a binding (with code) in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have code which supposed to do the exact same thing -> Create a binding and update the view.  But one works, while the other does not. Keep in mind this is a simplified example. The end goal is to have an array of different Types and then generate views depending on the type in the array.

Here is my code. Running it is self explanatory. Clicking on the first label updates the view, but clicking on the second label does not.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var objects: [Object1] = [
        Object1(integer: 0)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        PageViewController(pages: [
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               Text("This text gets updated").underline()
               Object1ViewDisplayer(object1: $objects[0]).padding(.bottom)

               Text("This text does *not* update. why?").underline()
               Object1ViewDisplayer(object1: Binding(get: { objects[0] }, set: { objects[0] = $0}))
            }
        ])
    }
}

protocol CommonProtocol {}
struct Object1: CommonProtocol {
    var integer: Int
}

struct Object1ViewDisplayer: View {
    @Binding var object1: Object1
    var body: some View {
        Text("[Click here] \(object1.integer)")
            .onTapGesture {
                object1.integer += 1
            }
    }
}
```

In order to get the PageViewController to work, I have just copied Apple's example. Please also copy it to get the above code to work.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct PageViewController<Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var pages: [Page]
    @State var currentPage: Int = 0

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        guard !context.coordinator.controllers.isEmpty else { return}
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [context.coordinator.controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            parent = pageViewController
            controllers = parent.pages.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard controllers.count != 1 else { return nil }
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 { return nil }
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard controllers.count != 1 else { return nil }
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == controllers.count { return nil }
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
            previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
            transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed,
               let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
               let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) {
                parent.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the first binding work, but the second one fail? And more importantly, how do i get the second one to work? It is needed to accomplish the goal stated above.

**[EDIT #1]**
Someone said in comments that removing the custom binding will update the 2nd view. This is true, but I think I need to use custom binding because the real code above will end up being the following:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var objects: [CommonProtocol] = [
        Object1(integer: 0)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        PageViewController(pages: [
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
//             Text("This text gets updated").underline()
//             Object1ViewDisplayer(object1: $objects[0]).padding(.bottom)
               Text("This text does *not* update. why?").underline()
               Object1ViewDisplayer(object1: Binding(get: { objects[0] as! Object1}, set: { objects[0] = $0}))
            }
        ])
    }
}
```

The `objects` array will be an array of Protocol types (to allow for multiple objects types) instead of a concrete type. And I have to be able to type caste the protocol back into its concrete type as shown in the edit. I only know how to do this with a custom binding.  If there is another way, then please let me know.

**[Edit #2]**
The weird thing is, if i comment out the PageViewController, the binding works as expected.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var objects: [Object1] = [
        Object1(integer: 0)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
//        PageViewController(pages: [
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
//             Text("This text gets updated").underline()
//             Object1ViewDisplayer(object1: $objects[0]).padding(.bottom)
               Text("This text does *not* update. why?").underline()
               Object1ViewDisplayer(object1: Binding(get: { objects[0] }, set: { objects[0] = $0}))
            }
//        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to same value on both objects?

Comment: @RajaKishan In the real app, there will be many different objects in there of different values / types.  But I simplified this example to directly show the bug I am experiencing.  The binding on the second object (the binding I plan to implement) is not working. The screen is not updated at all and I do not know how to fix it...

Comment: I checked if you remove custom binding then it will update the layout.

Comment: Please add the reason for custom binding too.

Comment: I have updated the question with the reason for the custom binding.

Comment: .onChange or .onReceive will help you might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone told me a solution offline.
I need to update Apple's PageViewController code to the following.

```swift
func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
    guard !context.coordinator.controllers.isEmpty else { return}
​
    for (page, vc) in zip(pages, context.coordinator.controllers) {
        let host = vc as! UIHostingController<Page>
        host.rootView = page
    }
​
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(
        [context.coordinator.controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
}
```